Dev tools in Chromium do not allow pasting
I am using Playwright with Chromium.
Every time a Chromium windows opens - When I debug a test, I can Not paste text into the console tabs.

I get this error:
"Warning: Don’t paste code into the DevTools Console that you don’t understand or haven’t reviewed yourself. This could allow attackers to steal your identity or take control of your computer. Please type ‘allow pasting’ below and hit Enter to allow pasting."
What can I do to make the dev tools enables for copy and paste? I know I can just type "allow pasting", but I do not wish to do so every time. When I use a normal Chrome window I do not encounter this problem.

This problem is discussed in github: [Feature]: disable the "allow pasting" warning in chrome devtools
And the --unsafely-disable-devtools-self-xss-warnings launch flag was merged to main: fix(chromium): allow pasting in DevTools without self-xss warning
If it is already part of a playwright release is however something I need to check.

Since Chromium/Chrome 126 (the most recent release), there is a feature flag to disable the paste protection:
chromium-browser --unsafely-disable-devtools-self-xss-warnings

It's described in this issue; just tested it and can confirm it works, at least on Linux.
